# What is the difference between the two methods below to delete actionbar home icon?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i want deleting the actionbar home icon. and two below code work for me but which is better?

1 or 2 ?

1:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
```

OR

2:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Choice #2 is far better IMHO. With #1, the home icon still exists, but simply cannot be seen. It might still respond to touch events, though.